# Getting the Depth of a json file in Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, depth

I am pretty new to Python and I am currently working with json files. My task is to get the nesting depth of a data set.

```
 data= [{'medprice': '1144942',
  'medprice_ia': '1664657',
  'percentchngprice': '1.01',
  'percentchngpriceia': '0.64',
  'source': 'Zillow',
  'year': '2003',
  'zipcode': '94123'}]
```

**JSON attribute with another object as value (or another object as member of a list value increases the depth of the file by 1**

I tried some ideas and this one seems to work the best regarding this task but I believe that I am getting the wrong nesting depth because the code above should return 1 as a nesting depth and not 2.

```
def depth(x):
    if type(x) is dict and x:
        return 1 + max(depth(x[a]) for a in x)
    if type(x) is list and x:
        return 1 + max(depth(a) for a in x)
    return 0
```

The only thing I changed is reducing the return value to only the value: something like this

```
if type(x) is list and x:
    for a in x:
      value= max(str(depth(a)))
      return value
```

Is there a better way to figure this out? Or am I missing something? Cheers!

Comment: It seems to me that `data` is a list (1) that contains a dict (2). What depth would a simple dict have?

Comment: A simple dictionary would have the depth 1 I think. I was confused, because I thought that in a json file the only thing that increases the value of the depth is by having a dict inside a dict e.g [{1: 'Sun', 2: {3: "mond",4:'Mon'}}], which I thought would have the depth of 2

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of depth. Examples [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_depth/) where `depth('[1, 2, 3]')` is 2, for example.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for your answer ! **-a flat JSON object with only atomic attribute values has depth 1.**
**- a JSON attribute with another object as value (or another oject as member of a list value!) increases the depth by 1.** Wouldnt this in my case mean that the depth of my data is 1 because every attribute in the list has only atomic values?

Comment: No, using the mariadb definition you have some atomic values (1), which are the keys and values of a dict (2). And that dict is inside a list (3). So, according to that defintion, your example would be depth 3.

Comment: But the mariadb definition is ultimately irrelevant. What is YOUR definition of depth? Your teachers/employers? (My definition would set atomic values' depth to 0, but again - that's irrelevant.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My dataset e.g has identical zip codes with various years and  pricing therefore I would say that my data list does not only contain  atomic values. If my json object contains not only atomic values the starting counter would be 0 My data dictionaries are inside a list, which means that the depth of this data would be 2 in my definition of depth.

Comment: 'atomic' in this context just means neither an array nor an object.